# Change value in tibble column element in R

Tags: r, variables, dplyr

I have a dataset :

```
library(tidyverse)
fac = factor(c("a","b","c"))
x = c(1,2,3)
d = tibble(fac,x);d
```

that looks like this :

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  fac       x
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 b         2
3 c         3
```

I want to change the value 2 of column x that corresponds to factor b with 3.14.

How can I do it in the dplyr pipeline framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
d %<>% 
   mutate(x = replace(x, fac == "b", 3.14))
```

-output

```
d
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  fac       x
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a      1   
2 b      3.14
3 c      3
```

Comment: Follow up question: if a want to change 2 with 3.14 and 3 with 7.2 in c? How can I do it ? Can you please update your answer ? It very clear though

Comment: @HungryHomer case_when can be used i..e `d %<>% mutate(x = case_when(fac == "b" ~ 3.14, fac == "c"  ~7.2, TRUE  ~as.numeric(x)))`

Comment: or `d %>% mutate(x = replace(x,fac %in% c("b","c"),c(3.14,7.2) ))`

Comment: It may be an issue when there are unequal replications for 'b', 'c'

Answer (score 4):

One alternative with `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(fac == "b", 3.14, x))
```

```
  fac       x
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a      1   
2 b      3.14
3 c      3
```